# Impact of a reset pin higher than VDD

Tags: voltage, level-shifting, reset

The datasheet of a chip describes the circuitry of the reset pin the following way:

[image]

The reset pin is described as a pull-down.

The chip is powered at 1.8V - the recommended/acceptable values are between 1.7V and 3.0V.

The reset pin belongs to another domain and toggles between 0 and 2.5V.

What is the risk for the chip to be powered at 1.8V and receive a signal at 2.5V?

Comment: The chip's datasheet should tell you this. Without knowing what chip it is nobody can answer.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the manufacturer and part number for the chip, and also a link to the datasheet. This will likely lead to the best possible answer.

Answer (score 0):

Likely: some diode in a transistor becomes reverse biased and the reset pin feeds into the power rail, which can sink more current than the transistor.

The datasheet should answer this in the "Absolute Maximum Ratings" section, typically digital I/O pins like a reset pin will list something like "Vcc + 0.3V", which both limits the voltage during operation and also implies that the pin may not be driven if the IC's supply is off.

Answer (score 0):

Look in the datasheet for maximum input values. It may or may not be "2.5V tolerant" (or tolerant of some other voltage greater than Vcc).

If it is not, you could damage the chip, cause it to draw excess current or otherwise act strangely- for example, unexpected current flows from inputs, or even damage other devices connected to the 1.8V rail (unlikely in this particular case).

And, as @Simon points out you need to consider the situation where the 1.8V supply disappears and the 2.5V supply is still present, particularly important if the 1.8V supply is not directly derived from the 2.5V supply with an LDO.

Answer (score 0):

My experience is that data sheet representations like that are more like cartoons of how the chip functions rather than the actual substrate on the chip.  You shouldn't use them for the type of question you're trying to get answered.

Careful reading of the datasheet should tell you allowable voltages on the pin of interest.